# How to pass aws credentials from env variables in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have the below code reading credentials from a file which is not safe. I would like to read from env var instead

```
  provisioner "file" {
    source      = ".credentials"
    destination = "credentials"
  }
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "mkdir -p .aws",
      "mv credentials .aws/credentials"
    ]
  }
```

I have exported the variables already but how do I use it in the above code?

Exports:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="anaccesskey"
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="asecretkey"
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here and why? As written this has nothing to do with AWS specifically.

Comment: Can you elaborate why do you need it in that form? If that is for an EC2 instance, you might want to use an IAM instance role.

Comment: @MarkoE I don't want to commit the credentials to git repo because credentials are getting exposed. I would to pass credentials via env

Comment: Can you add the entire resource block to the question? Because from this it looks to me like you want to give an EC2 instance some credentials, and using API keys is not really a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

I read in the comments that, you are deploying from Git.

If the repo is on GitHub -

You should use Role instead of user credentials as a good practice. Its not complex as well.

The detailed steps are published here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/use-iam-roles-to-connect-github-actions-to-actions-in-aws/

You define OIDC provider in AWS, define a role with required permissions, add your GitHub repo in the trusted relation, so it can assume that AWS role.

Now use following action in the GitHub workflow.

```
  - name: configure aws credentials
    uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1.7.0
    with:
      role-to-assume: <arn:aws:iam::111122223333:role/GitHubAction-AssumeRoleWithAction> #change to reflect your IAM role’s ARN
      role-session-name: GitHub_to_AWS_via_FederatedOIDC
      aws-region: ${{ env.AWS_REGION }}
```

For GitLab or other alternatives as well, there would be a way to use Role.